# Alpha and omega limit sets

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems

What are all the possible $α$- and $ω$-limit sets of points for the linear system of equations $x'=Ax$ given by the following matrices $A$:

I guess I don't really know how to get started, Could I have some guidance?
So I was told to calculate the eigenvalues (fine) and eigenvectors (I kind of forgot how to do that...)

1. $
      A=
     \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
      -4 & -2 \\
      3 & 11 \\
     \end{array} } \right]
   $

$λ_1=-10$ $λ_2=-5$

for $λ_1=-10$:

eigenvector $
   =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  1 \\
   3 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

for $λ_2=-5$:

eigenvector $
   =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  2 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

2. $
      A=
     \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
      1 & 1 \\
      3 & 1 \\
     \end{array} } \right]
   $

$λ_1=4$ $λ_2=-2$

for $λ_1=4$:

eigenvector $
   =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  1 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

for $λ_2=-2$:

eigenvector $
   =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  -1 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

3. $
      A=
     \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
      4 & 5 \\
      -5 & -2 \\
     \end{array} } \right]
   $

$λ_1=1+4i$ $λ_2=1-4i$

for $λ_1=1+4i$:

eigenvector $
   =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  -3/5-(4i)/5 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

for $λ_1=1-4i$:

eigenvector $
   =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  -3/5+(4i)/5 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

Comment: You should start by writing down the definition. The next step would be to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrices.

Comment: @studiosus So i found the eigenvalues and vectors as you suggested,

Comment: but im not really sure how to progress..